# use tabs in sharepoint 2013 list new form

Tags: newform

I have large numbers of columns so want to use tabs feature in list new form based on categories. How to implement this using jquery? please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **[HillbillyTabify.js](http://www.markrackley.net/scripts/jquery.HillbillyTabify.min.js)** to tabify SharePoint forms.

reference : http://www.markrackley.net/2015/12/03/tabify-your-sharepoint-forms/

Comment: oooh, I've read some bad things about HillbillyTabify.js on this site - I'd do some extra reading on it first before you use it.  I've heard it has bugs - in fact, here is one post I just found [link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/176204/hillbillytabs-3-0-in-sharepoint-2013-select-box-bug)